# Unnecessary logs on every HTTP request after upgrade from Spring Boot 1 to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, tomcat

After upgrade from `Spring Boot 1` to `Spring Boot 2` I get extra logs on every HTTP request on all endpoints, e.g.:

```
169.190.0.27 - - [18/Nov/2019:11:13:39 +0000] "GET /project-name/0.0.1/jobs HTTP/1.1" 200 329
```

and here is an example of log on non existing endpoint:

```
169.190.0.27 - - [18/Nov/2019:11:16:13 +0000] "GET /project-name/0.0.1/test HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

These logs don't go through the main logger as I have JSON formatting set up and these logs don't have it. I don't know it it's done by Spring or Tomcat.
Any idea how to get rid of these logs?